# PHP - Why am I getting an output of just 'array'?. echoing an array

Tags: php, arrays

This code is suppose to find the highest number of nested arrays.  everytime I output the number by 'echo' is gives my the string ' array' instead of the highest number, which should be '4'.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    "1",
    "2",
    array(
        "3",
        "4"
    )
);
foreach ($arr as $value) 
{
    if (is_array($value)) 
    {
        foreach ($value as $value2) 
        {
            $max_array = array(
                $value
            );
            // no deeper levels

        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $max_array = array(
            $value
        );
    }
}
$ash = max($max_array);

echo $ash;
?>
```

This error just started happening, that is why I can't figure  it out : the error displays:

`Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 17 Array`

Comment: what is the output your are getting for print_r($ash);

Comment: Rather call your function recursive if an array.

Comment: Why the hell should he call a recursive function for a simple array output? And anyways, this guy is obviously a beginner, how can he know what a recursive function is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    "1",
    "2",
    array(
        "3",
        "4"
    )
);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo $value . '<br>';
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $value2) {
            echo $value2 . '<br>';
            $max_array = array(
                $value2            //your mistake was here(you had written $value
                                   //it becomes array within an array i.e.
                                   //$max_array = array( array());
                                   //so d output was array
                                   //Execute this and u will get the solution
            );
            // no deeper levels

        }
    } else {
        $max_array = array(
            $value
        );
    }
}
$ash = max($max_array);

echo $ash;
```

1. Read the comments properly you will get the solution
2. Execute this and check

Answer (score 1):

Echoing an array like that doesnt work. You will need either `print_r` or a loop:

```
foreach($ash as $a) {
    echo $a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is an alternative solution though (without making use of loops). Works on any arrays with multiple nesting.

You can simplify your code like this to find the largest number in the array.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    "1",
    "2",
    array(
        "3",
        "4"
    )
);
$str = json_encode($arr);
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
echo max(array_unique($matches[0])); //"prints" 4
```

The following code just JSON encodes your array and then uses a regular expression to match the numbers and finally we use `max` to find the largest number.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    "1",
    "2",
    array(
        "3",
        "4"
    )
);
$max_array = array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $value2) {
            $max_array = $value;

        }
    } else {
        $max_array = $value;
    }
}
$ash = max($max_array);
echo $ash;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to convert at array, an ordered map with associated values to keys, into a string.

In order to render your array you will need to adopt one of the following methodologies:

**Method One:**
Dump the entire data type (works for arrays, strings, booleans and floats.)

```
var_dump($array);
```

**Method Two:**
Prints the array in human readable format.

```
print_r($array);
```

**Method Three**
Look through each of the keys and print the keys and values.

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) { 
     print "Array Key :: {$key}, Array Value :: {$value}";
}
```

For more information relating to arrays please reference : https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

use below function:-

```
function findMax($array){
    if(is_array($array)){
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            $array[$key] = findMax($value);
        }
        return max($array);
    }else{
        return $array;
    }
}


echo findMax($arr);
```

This function will **return maximum value from an multidimentional array**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `array_reduce` function to handle any depth of array:

```
$arr = array(
    "1",
    "2",
    array(
        "3",
        "4",
        array(
            "5",
            "7"
        ),
        "8"
    )
);

// This will output "8"
echo array_reduce($arr, 'MaxRecursive');

function MaxRecursive($max, $value)
{
    // If we have an array, loop through it and
    // get the max for each entry
    if (is_array($value))
    {
        $values = array();
        foreach ($value as $val)
        {
            $values[] = MaxRecursive(0, $val);
        }
        $value = max($values);
    }

    $max = $max > $value ? $max : $value;
    return $max;
}
```

Comment: This will probably work, but have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21746469/1338292) for a simpler way :)